# .dll is not a valid win32 application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-word

Hi I am having an issue with my word addin .net project. Basically I am trying to compile and run it. However I keep getting an error message saying

[image]

Now I have looked into this and according to other users on stack I need to change my build property to any cpu which I have done to no avail

[image]

[image]

Can someone advise me please on what to do here because I don't know what's wrong? Thanks very much

Comment: When using Any CPU configuration, in the final .dll or .exe you compile will be a x86 and a x64 binary images that are run depending on your Windows architecture. So, if your Windows is 64bit, the x64 image will run and so on. Try to compile it to x86 and it might work. (also check that your office package is 32 or 64bit)

Comment: So I have tried switching to compile to specifically 64 bit (My windows) but it wouldn't work. However I checked my office package and it is 32 bit..... I will try downloading 64bit

Comment: If you run Windows and Office both on 64bit it makes sense to compile it to 64bit. Personally on my Office addins I generate separated binaries (32 & 64 bit) and install them accordingly. Hope you get it to work on Office 64bit because I can see no other problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to run a DLL as if it were an exe?

Comment: Hmmmm I'm not sure actually why it's loading that..... I cloned it with the idea it has been set up right and ran into all these issues..... I have the startup project set so I dunno why it's looking at a dll

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem:  ie. "cock pit error"

Do:  Visual Studio > Build menu > Rebuild

Don't:   or Debug menu > Start Debugging

I kept hitting .

Answer (score 0):

My issue went away when I realized I was in Folder View!  My Solution Explorer looked like A.  I double-clicked on the ".sln" file and got B, and then I could pull up properties and run.

[image]
Of course, when I was in Folder View, I couldn't pull up properties, so this wouldn't apply to OP's scenario, but it's something simple to remember to check if one gets this error.